# What's the best way to dedupe a table?

Tags: sql, algorithm, performance, duplicates

I've seen a couple of solutions for this, but I'm wondering what the best and most efficient way is to de-dupe a table. You can use code (SQL, etc.) to illustrate your point, but I'm just looking for basic algorithms. I assumed there would already be a question about this on SO, but I wasn't able to find one, so if it already exists just give me a heads up.

(Just to clarify - I'm referring to getting rid of duplicates in a table that has an incremental automatic PK and has some rows that are duplicates in everything but the PK field.)

Comment: **Removing Duplicate Records:** http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1438651/Removing-Duplicate-Records.htm **How to remove duplicate rows from a table in SQL Server:** http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139444 **Remove duplicate entries / rows a mySQL database table:** http://www.justin-cook.com/wp/2006/12/12/remove-duplicate-entries-rows-a-mysql-database-table/ **Removing Duplicates from a Table in SQL Server:** http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/removing-duplicates-from-a-table-in-sql-server/ That should get you going, if you need more examples please let me

Answer (score 31):

Using analytic function row_number:

```
WITH CTE (col1, col2, dupcnt)
AS
(
SELECT col1, col2,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col1) AS dupcnt
FROM Youtable
)
DELETE
FROM CTE
WHERE dupcnt > 1
GO
```

Comment: Since when can you `DELETE FROM CTE`?

Comment: @Kev You can DELETE from a CTE so long as the modification would only change a single base table, which should be the case here.

Comment: Does seem to work on PostgreSQL - may be just a SQL Server thing?

Comment: Won't this delete all entries that have duplicates rather than just deleting the duplicate entries?

Comment: @Woody1193 no. It only deletes rows with dupecnt > 1

Answer (score 24):

`SELECT DISTINCT <insert all columns but the PK here> FROM foo`. Create a temp table using that query (the syntax varies by RDBMS but there's typically a `SELECT … INTO` or `CREATE TABLE AS` pattern available), then blow away the old table and pump the data from the temp table back into it.

Answer (score 13):

Adding the actual code here for future reference

So, there are 3 steps, and therefore 3 SQL statements:

Step 1: Move the non duplicates (unique tuples) into a temporary table

```
CREATE TABLE new_table as
SELECT * FROM old_table GROUP BY [column to remove duplicates by];
```

Step 2: delete the old table (or rename it)
We no longer need the table with all the duplicate entries, so drop it!

```
DROP TABLE old_table;
```

Step 3: rename the new_table to the name of the old_table

```
RENAME TABLE new_table TO old_table;
```

And of course, don't forget to fix your buggy code to stop inserting duplicates!

Comment: `myTable.randomColumn not in GROUP BY clause` :(
 Looks like I can't group by a single column without providing aggregation functions for all of them.

Comment: What is the purpose of `WHERE 1`?

Comment: None. In this context, WHERE 1 is essentially redundant and serves no practical purpose. The GROUP BY clause alone is sufficient to group rows by the specified column and remove duplicates. Post updated to reflect this oversight thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Deduping is rarely simple. That's because the records to be dedupped often have slightly different values is some of the fields. Therefore choose which record to keep can be problematic. Further, dups are often people records and it is hard to identify if the two John Smith's are two people or one person who is duplicated. So spend a lot (50% or more of the whole project) of your time defining what constitutes a dup and how to handle the differences and child records.

How do you know which is the correct value? Further dedupping requires that you handle all child records not orphaning any. What happens when you find that by changing the id on the child record you are suddenly violating one of the unique indexes or constraints - this will happen eventually and your process needs to handle it. If you have chosen foolishly to apply all your constraints only thorough the application, you may not even know the constraints are violated. When you have 10,000 records to dedup, you aren't going to go through the  application to dedup one at a time. If the constraint isn't in the database, lots of luck in maintaining data integrity when you dedup.

A further complication is that dups don't always match exactly on the name or address. For instance a salesrep named Joan Martin may be a dup of a sales rep names Joan Martin-Jones especially if they have the same address and email. OR you could have John or Johnny in the name. Or the same street address except one record abbreveiated ST. and one spelled out Street. In SQL server you can use SSIS and fuzzy grouping to also identify near matches.  These are often the most common dups as the fact that weren't exact matches is why they got put in as dups in the first place.

For some types of dedupping, you may need a user interface, so that the person doing the dedupping can choose which of two values to use for a particular field. This is especially true if the person who is being dedupped is in two or more roles. It could be that the data for a particular role is usually better than the data for another role. Or it could be that only the users will know for sure which is the correct value or they may need to contact people to find out if they are genuinely dups or simply two people with the same name.

Answer (score 10):

Here's the method I use if you can get your dupe criteria into a group by statement and your table has an id identity column for uniqueness:

```
delete t
from tablename t
inner join  
(
    select date_time, min(id) as min_id
    from tablename
    group by date_time
    having count(*) > 1
) t2 on t.date_time = t2.date_time
where t.id > t2.min_id
```

In this example the date_time is the grouping criteria, if you have more than one column make sure to join on all of them.

In PostgreSQL (that doesn't allow inner join with delete) this works:

```
delete 
from tablename t
where t.id in (
    select t.id
    from tablename t
    inner join  
    (
        select name, min(id) as min_id
        from tablename
        group by date_time
        having count(*) > 1
    ) t2 on t.name = t2.name
    where t.id > t2.min_id
)
```

Comment: why not just:
`delete from table where pk_id not in (select min(pk_id)  from table group by COL1)`

Comment: @Dshook's technique avoids the MySQL error, "Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'tablename' for update in FROM clause".

Answer (score 3):

For those of you who prefer a quick and dirty approach, just list all the columns that together define a unique record and create a unique index with those columns, like so:

ALTER IGNORE TABLE `TABLE_NAME` ADD UNIQUE (`column1`,`column2`,`column3`)

You can drop the unique index afterwords.

Comment: I love this solution, but in MySQL the `ignore` keyword is removed as of version 5.7. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456520/mysql-alter-ignore-table-add-unique-what-will-be-truncated It produces an error now.

Answer (score 3):

I am taking the one from DShook and providing a dedupe example where you would keep only the record with the highest date.

In this example say I have 3 records all with the same app_id, and I only want to keep the one with the highest date:

```
DELETE t
FROM @USER_OUTBOX_APPS t
INNER JOIN  
(
    SELECT 
         app_id
        ,max(processed_date) as max_processed_date
    FROM @USER_OUTBOX_APPS
    GROUP BY app_id
    HAVING count(*) > 1
) t2 on 
    t.app_id = t2.app_id
WHERE 
    t.processed_date < t2.max_processed_date
```

Answer (score 2):

This can dedupe the duplicated values in `c1`:

```
select * from foo
minus
select f1.* from foo f1, foo f2
where f1.c1 = f2.c1 and f1.c2 > f2.c2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
delete from yourTable 
where Id not in (
    select min(id) 
    from yourTable
    group by <Unique Columns>
)
```

where id is whatever is your unique id in the table.  (Could be customerNumber or whatever)

If you don't have a Unique Id, you can add one (every SQL table should already have Id as first column, but

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable
ADD Id int identity(1,1)
```

Do your delete (above) and then drop the column.

Better than creating a whole new table, or any of the other cryptic stuff I've seen.  Note, pretty much the same as in a comment here, but this is what I've done for years.

Comment: I would add that if you select min (id) you are keeping the first one created, if you want the last one created to be kept instead, you can use max(id)..  This is often very important, as it is often the case where you want either the first or the last

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a hash for each row (excluding the PK), store it in a new column (or if you can't add new columns, can you move the table to a temp staging area?), and then look for all other rows with the same hash. Of course, you would have to be able to ensure that your hash function doesn't produce the same code for different rows.

If two rows are duplicate, does it matter which you get rid of? Is it possible that other data are dependent on both of the duplicates? If so, you will have to go through a few steps:

- Find the dupes
- Choose one of them as `dupeA` to eliminate
- Find all data dependent on `dupeA`
- Alter that data to refer to `dupeB`
- delete `dupeA`.

This could be easy or complicated, depending on your existing data model.

This whole scenario sounds like a maintenance and redesign project. If so, best of luck!!

Comment: how exactly do you ensure that hashes don't produce the same code for different data. When using hashes there is always a possibility for dupes. Downvote.

Comment: @EsbenP: I've seen zipped strings used as a sort of hash for the original strings. At least you don't get dupes.

Comment: I was assuming that no other data is dependent on the PK field. But that's an interesting point - what would you do if that was so? That would make it a whole lot more complicated... Any ideas?

Comment: why bother hashing when you can use distinct.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL, you may use the INSERT IGNORE INTO table SELECT xy FROM unkeyed_table;

For an algorithm, if you can assume that to-be-primary keys may be repeated, but a to-be-primary-key uniquely identifies the content of the row, than hash only the to-be-primary key and check for repetition.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should require nothing more then just grouping by all columns except the id and choosing one row from every group - for simplicity just the first row, but this does not actually matter besides you have additional constraints on the id.

Or the other way around to get rid of the rows ... just delete all rows accept a single one from all groups.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I've run into, in real life.

Assume you have a table of external/3rd party logins for users, and you're going to merge two users and want to dedupe on the provider/provider key values.

```
    ;WITH Logins AS
    (
        SELECT [LoginId],[UserId],[Provider],[ProviderKey]
        FROM [dbo].[UserLogin] 
        WHERE [UserId]=@FromUserID -- is the user we're deleting
              OR [UserId]=@ToUserID -- is the user we're moving data to
    ), Ranked AS 
    (
        SELECT Logins.*
            , [Picker]=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                       PARTITION BY [Provider],[ProviderKey]
                       ORDER BY CASE WHEN [UserId]=@FromUserID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        FROM Logins
    )
    MERGE Logins AS T
    USING Ranked AS S
    ON S.[LoginId]=T.[LoginID]
    WHEN MATCHED AND S.[Picker]>1 -- duplicate Provider/ProviderKey
                 AND T.[UserID]=@FromUserID -- safety check 
    THEN DELETE
    WHEN MATCHED AND S.[Picker]=1 -- the only or best one
                 AND T.[UserID]=@FromUserID
    THEN UPDATE SET T.[UserID]=@ToUserID
    OUTPUT $action, DELETED.*, INSERTED.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

These methods will work, but without an explicit id as a PK then determining which rows to delete could be a problem. The bounce out into a temp table delete from original and re-insert without the dupes seems to be the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

For deduplicate / dedupe / remove duplication / remove repeated rows / 数据库 除重 / 数据库 去除 重复记录， there are multiple ways.

1. If duplicated rows are exact the same, use group by

   create table TABLE_NAME_DEDUP
   as select column1, column2, ... (all column names) 
   from TABLE_NAME group by column1, column2,   -- all column names

Then TABLE_NAME_DEDUP  is the deduplicated table.

For example,

```
create table test (t1 varchar(5), t2 varchar(5));
insert into test  values ('12345', 'ssdlh');
insert into test  values ('12345', 'ssdlh');
create table test_dedup as
select * from test 
group by t1, t2;
-----optional
--remove original table and rename dedup table to previous table
--this is not recommend in dev or qa. DROP table test; Alter table test_dedup rename to test;
```

2. You have a rowid, the rowid has duplication but other columns are different 
   Records partial same, this may happened in a transactional system while update a row, and the rows failed to update will have nulls.
   You want to remove the duplication

   create table test_dedup as
   select column1, column2, ... (all column names) 
   from (
      select *
     , row_number() over (partition by rowid order by column1, column2, ... (all column names except rowid)  ) as cn
   from test
   ) where cn =1

This is using the feature that when you use order by, the null value will be ordered behind the non-null value.

```
create table test (rowid_ varchar(5), t1 varchar(5), t2 varchar(5));
insert into test  values ('12345', 'ssdlh', null);
insert into test  values ('12345', 'ssdlh', 'lhbzj');
create table test_dedup as
select rowid_, t1, t2 from
（select *
  , row_number() over (partition by rowid_ order by t1, t2) as cn
  from  test)
 where cn =1
 ;

-----optional
--remove original table and rename dedup table to previous table
--this is not recommend in dev or qa. DROP table test; Alter table test_dedup rename to test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the problem today, none of the existing answers helped me. Assume you want to deduplicate your table named `your_table`.

**Step 1: Create a new table with deduped values**

If borrowed this code from somewhere else on StackOverflow but can't seem to find it again. It works fine against PostgreSQL. It creates a table `your_table_deduped` where `(col1, col2)` are unique.

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table_deduped AS
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE ctid NOT IN
(SELECT ctid FROM
  (SELECT ctid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY ctid) AS rnum
  FROM your_table) t
WHERE t.rnum > 1);
```

**Step 2: Replace your first table with the deduped copy**

We only delete the values in this step, because it allows us to keep the indexes, constraints, etc. in your table.

```sql
DELETE FROM your_table;
INSERT INTO your_table
SELECT * FROM your_table_deduped;
```

**Step 3: Delete the deduped copy**

```sql
DROP TABLE site_daily_kpis_dedup;
```

And voila, you have deduplicated your table!