# Remove duplicate rows from table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

I'd like to create an unique index on single attribute in a huge table, but there are duplicite values, so I need to remove the duplicity. Only duplicite records can be deleted. What is the best solution in phpmyadmin or mysql query to do this?

The only solution I figured out is to make select into another table, but I'd prefer to delete data from original table.

The table looks like this (I'd like to put unique index on `id`)

```
|id|...
+--+---
| 1|x
| 2|a   <-- duplicity
| 2|b   <-- duplicity
| 3|c
| 4|d
```

This would be the best result

```
|id|...
+--+---
| 1|x
| 2|a
| 3|c
| 4|d
```

This is also acceptable result

```
|id|...
+--+---
| 1|x
| 3|c
| 4|d
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, just creating a `UNIQUE` index will remove the duplicates. If not, just create a temporary table that will `INSERT ... SELECT DISTINCT id...`

Comment: Why is `(2, a)` more preferable than `(2, b)`?

Comment: @eggyal: `2, a` is not preferable than `2, b`, but one of them must go, I don't care which one.
@njk: attempt to create unique index results in error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE my_table ADD UNIQUE INDEX (id);
```

Comment: Works great, 10.000 rows removed instantly, thanks!

Comment: After having searched for that answer, I can confirm the first item (smallest ID) will be kept : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456520/mysql-alter-ignore-table-add-unique-what-will-be-truncated

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE  a 
FROM    tableName a
        LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT id, min(colName) x
                FROM tableName
                GROUP BY id
            ) c
        ON a.id = c.id AND
            a.colName = c.x
WHERE c.id IS NULL;
```

- [**SEE SQLFIDDLE Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0da14/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM table 
WHERE id IN 
   (SELECT id FROM table, (SELECT id, count(*) dNum FROM table GROUP BY id) x 
     WHERE id = x.id      
   ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT dNum-1)
```