# Want to delete multiple row but not first row for same property in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like

table name : emailvalue

```
--------------------------------------
| email                    |   value |
-----------------------------------
|  ab@gmail.com            |  A      |
--------------------------------------
|  ab@gmail.com            |  B      |
--------------------------------------
|  ab@gmail.com            |  C      |
--------------------------------------
|  cccc@gmail.com          |  F      |
--------------------------------------
|  dd@gmail.com            |  G      |
--------------------------------------
|  dd@gmail.com            |  A      |
--------------------------------------
|  dd@gmail.com            |  H      |
--------------------------------------
```

I want to delete all for same email without first row. how i will right the sql in my sql

the SQL should delete this 2 row in mysql

```
--------------------------------------
|  ab@gmail.com            |  B      |
--------------------------------------
|  ab@gmail.com            |  C      |
--------------------------------------   

 and also        

 --------------------------------------
|  dd@gmail.com            |  A      |
 --------------------------------------
|  dd@gmail.com            |  H      |
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a *first row* in relational databases. Tabales are *multisets* (somtimes called *bags*) of records, not *lists* of records. Keeping this in mind, please clarify what you mean by *first row*.

Comment: See the table there are 3 row for email ab@gmail.com . i want to delete last 2 row of those 3 row..

Comment: I told you there is no such thing as a *first row*. Likewise, there is no such thing as *last 2 rows*. You have to find some other criterion on which to base the descision about which records to remove.

Comment: How do you build that order of our table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it:

```
DELETE t1 FROM emailvalue t1
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT email, value
  FROM emailvalue
  GROUP BY email
) t2 on t2.email = t1.email AND t2.value = t1.value
WHERE t2.value is null;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
delete t
from your_table t
left join 
(
  select email, min(value) as minv
  from your_table
  group by email
) x on x.email = t.email and x.minv = t.value
where x.minv is null
```

Comment: Won't that only delete the one where value = C in OP's example?

Comment: no, it will delete all rows for each email where value is not the min(value) = A

Comment: Ah, yes, I see. Good job.

Comment: there is no dependency on value just need to delete from 2 row for a specific email please see the second example of the table..

Comment: @SarwarCSE: What you don't understand is that there is no second element until you order your data by something. Do you have an id column or how do you know what is the first and what the second element?

Comment: @juergend ok if there is another property named ID with auto increment then ?

Comment: @SarwarCSE: Is that id the order? Is the first entry the entry with the lowest id you want to keep?

Comment: @juergend this sql show a error which is 
[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'x.value' in 'where clause'

Comment: @SarwarCSE: Of course. Replace with `x.minv`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `emailvalue` ADD UNIQUE INDEX(`email`);
```

[MySQL remove duplicates from big database quick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651999/mysql-remove-duplicates-from-big-database-quick)

[MySQL: ALTER IGNORE TABLE ADD UNIQUE, what will be truncated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456520/mysql-alter-ignore-table-add-unique-what-will-be-truncated)