# Delete duplicates from db

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have table like following

```
id | a_id | b_id | success
--------------------------
1    34      43      1
2    34      84      1
3    34      43      0
4    65      43      1
5    65      84      1
6    93      23      0
7    93      23      0
```

I want delete duplicates with same a_id and b_id, but I want keep one record. If possible kept record should be with success=1. So in example table third and sixth/seventh record should be deleted. How to do this?

I'm using MySQL 5.1

Comment: check this link http://www.besttechtools.com/articles/article/sql-query-to-delete-duplicate-rows

Comment: But my case is more complicated and I don't know how to keep one record with succes = 1 (if possible)

Comment: if say two records are duplicates with success = 0, can u delete both, or need one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task is simple:

- Find the minimum number of records that should not be deleted.
- Delete the other records.

The Oracle way,

```
delete from sample_table where id not in(
select id from
(
 Select id, success,row_number()  
 over (partition by a_id,b_id order by success desc) rown 
 from sample_table
) 
where (success = 1 and rown = 1) or rown=1)
```

The solution in mysql:

Will give you the minimum ids that should not be deleted.:

```
Select id from (SELECT * FROM report ORDER BY success desc) t 
group by  t.a_id, t.b
```

o/p:

```
ID
1
2
4
5
6
```

You can delete the other rows.

```
  delete from report where id not in (the above query)
```

The consolidated DML:

```
delete from report 
  where id not in (Select id 
                    from (SELECT * FROM report 
                          ORDER BY success desc) t 
                    group by  t.a_id, t.b_id)
```

Now doing a Select on report:

```
ID  A_ID    B_ID    SUCCESS
1   34       43     1
2   34       84     1
4   65       43     1
5   65       84     1
6   93       23     0
```

You can check the documentation of how the group by clause works when no aggregation function is provided:

> When using this feature, all rows in each group should have the same
>   values for the columns that are omitted from the GROUP BY part. The
>   server is free to return any value from the group, so the results are
>   indeterminate unless all values are the same.

So just performing an order by '`success` before the group by would allow us to get the first duplicate row with `success = 1`.

Comment: I dont think MySQL supports "over ( partition by".

Comment: oops - the solution is in oracle sql, wait a minute let me transform the logic to mysql.

Comment: @BatScream Did you transformed query?

Comment: Updated my answer with mysql solution. - @andrzej1_1

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table 
  AS (SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE 1 AND success = 1 GROUP BY a_id,b_id);
DROP TABLE old_table;
RENAME TABLE new_table TO old_table;
```

This method will create a new table with a temporary name, and copy all the deduped rows which have success = 1 from the old table.  The old table is then dropped and the new table is renamed to the name of the old table.

If I understand your question correctly, this is probably the simplest solution. (though I don't know if it's really efficient or not)

Comment: So what if any of duplicates has not succes=1?

Comment: Well your question said that those should also be removed, and this would do that.  This preserves rows 1, 2, 4, & 5

Comment: 'Sixth/seventh' mean sixth OR seventh

Comment: well removing the `AND success = 1` would give you that result for this example data, however it also removes the guarantee that you will favor the success=1 rows on other data.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

If procedural programming is available to you like e.g. pl/sql it is fairly simple. If you on the other hand is looking for a clean SQL solution it might be possible but not very "nice". Below is an example in pl/sql:

```
begin
  for x in ( select a_id, b_id
             from   table
             having count(*) > 1
             group  by a_id, b_id )
  loop
    for y in ( select *
               from   table
               where  a_id = x.a_id
               and    b_id = x.b_id
               order  by success desc )
    loop
      delete from table
      where  a_id = y.a_id
      and    b_id = y.b_id
      and    id != x.id;
      exit; // Only do the first row
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
```

This is the idea: For each duplicated combination of a_id and b_id select all the instances ordered so that any with success=1 is up first. Delete all of that combination except the first - being the successful one if any.

or perhaps:

```
declare
  l_a_id integer := -1;
  l_b_id integer := -1;
begin
  for x in ( select *
             from   table
             order  by a_id, b_id, success desc )
  loop
    if  x.a_id = l_a_id and x.b_id = l_b_id
    then
      delete from table where  id = x.id;
    end if;
    l_a_id := x.a_id;
    l_b_id := x.b_id;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Good idea to ordering success, but I need query to MySQL

Comment: I'm sorry - I am not into procedural MySQL. Maybe someone else can kick in?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, if you dont want to care about which record is maintained, a single alter table will work.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE tbl_name
ADD UNIQUE INDEX(a_id, b_id)
```

It ignores the duplicate records and maintain only the unique records.

A useful links : 
[MySQL: ALTER IGNORE TABLE ADD UNIQUE, what will be truncated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456520/mysql-alter-ignore-table-add-unique-what-will-be-truncated)