# remove duplicate entry in SQL database with null fields

Tags: mysql, sql

how can i remove duplicate entry in SQL database when there are some null fields:
i have a table Mesure2 that contains duplicate entries, some having null fields, i have removed the other duplicate entries like this:

```
INSERT Mesures SELECT distinct * FROM Mesures2;
```

but there is still duplicate entries with null field that prevent me from creating Keys:

```
MariaDB [sidonie2]> ALTER TABLE Mesures ADD PRIMARY KEY (`N° Fiche`,Date,Angle,Sépar,`Nb Nuits`,CodeObs,Instrument,dimension,Réf,Nota);
 ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2928-1892.93-258.6-03.34-2-JNS---LDS-' for key 'PRIMARY'

MariaDB [sidonie2]> select * from Mesures where `N° Fiche` = 2928 and Date = 1892.93;
  +-----------+---------+-------+--------+----------+---------+-----------+------------+------+------+
  | N° Fiche  | Date    | Angle | Sépar  | Nb Nuits | CodeObs | dimension | Instrument | Réf  | Nota |
  +-----------+---------+-------+--------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+------+------+
  |      2928 | 1892.93 | 258.6 | 03.34  |        2 | JNS     | NULL      | NULL       | LDS  |      |
  |      2928 | 1892.93 | 258.6 | 03.34  |        2 | JNS     | NULL      | NULL       | LDS  | NULL |
  +-----------+---------+-------+--------+----------+---------+-----------+------------+------+------+
```

how can i eliminate duplicate that differs only by a Null and empty same field (here it is Nota field but could be any one else)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you want to preserve the nulls as NULL:

```
INSERT Mesures (`N° Fiche`,Date,Angle,Sépar,`Nb Nuits`,CodeObs,Instrument,dimension,Réf,Nota)
SELECT DISTINCT
    `N° Fiche`,
    Date,
    Angle,
    Sépar,
    `Nb Nuits`,
    CodeObs,
    Instrument,
    dimension,
    Réf,
    nullif(Nota,'')
FROM Mesures2;
```

Or if you want the nulls to be empty strings:

```
INSERT Mesures (`N° Fiche`,Date,Angle,Sépar,`Nb Nuits`,CodeObs,Instrument,dimension,Réf,Nota)
SELECT DISTINCT
    `N° Fiche`,
    Date,
    Angle,
    Sépar,
    `Nb Nuits`,
    CodeObs,
    Instrument,
    dimension,
    Réf,
    ifnull(Nota,'')
FROM Mesures2;
```

Note that `nullif()` and `ifnull()` are very different functions.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i use ifnull() (or nullif) on fields.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange that you would define an entire row as a primary key.  Have you considered an auto-increment field?

In any case, if you want to remove NULL values, do it in the insert:

```
INSERT Mesures(`N° Fiche`, Date, Angle, Sépar, `Nb Nuits`, CodeObs, Instrument, dimension, Réf, Nota)
    SELECT distinct `N° Fiche`, Date, Angle, Sépar, `Nb Nuits`, CodeObs, Instrument, dimension, Réf, Nota
    FROM Mesures2
    WHERE `N° Fiche` IS NOT NULL AND
          Date IS NOT NULL AND
          Angle IS NOT NULL AND
          Sépar IS NOT NULL AND
          `Nb Nuits` IS NOT NULL AND
          CodeObs IS NOT NULL AND
          Instrument IS NOT NULL AND
          dimension IS NOT NULL AND
          Réf IS NOT NULL AND
          Nota IS NOT NULL;
```

This approach does assume that the table is empty before the `INSERT`.

Comment: about the primary key,the table was not done be me and i trying to change this,about the answer if i do that suppose i will get only the line having no null field,but  i must keep all the distinct lines unless they differ by having one or more null field which duplicate with an empty field

Comment: no it's not what i want, this query will select and insert the distinct data that have no NULL field but  that will remove valid data only because they  have a NULL field, not good.

Answer (score -1):

```
alter IGNORE TABLE tablename add UNIQUE index(col_name)
```

Comment: Are you sure that this removes any row in the database? I don't think so

Comment: At one point, this was possible with MySQL, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456520/mysql-alter-ignore-table-add-unique-what-will-be-truncated