# MySQL delete duplicate rows based on row number

Tags: mysql

I want to delete some duplicate rows (ID is duplicate), based on its row number (there is no primary key), so that I can thereafter make the ID column my primary key.

My current query does give back the correct rows I want to delete:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE @row_number:=@row_number NOT IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT MIN(@row_number:=@row_number) 
        FROM table_name
        GROUP BY id
    ) x
);
```

But when I try to delete them using the following query, nothing happens.

```
DELETE
FROM table_name
WHERE @row_number:=@row_number NOT IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT MIN(@row_number:=@row_number) 
        FROM table_name
        GROUP BY id
    ) x
);
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for setting primary key and remove all duplicated ids:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `table_name` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Solution two:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name AS
SELECT * FROM old_table_name GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: I get an 1064 general error when running this. "You have got an error in SQL Syntax..."

Comment: Isn't IGNORE depreciated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456520/mysql-alter-ignore-table-add-unique-what-will-be-truncated