# Python Postgresql dedupe consuming a lot of time. Can there be any optimization?

Tags: python, postgresql, python-dedupe

I am using postgres dedupe [example code](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe-examples/blob/master/pgsql_example/pgsql_example.py). 
For 10,000 rows, it is consuming 163 seconds. I found that it is consuming most of the time in this part:

```
full_data = []
cluster_membership = collections.defaultdict(lambda : 'x')
for cluster_id, (cluster, score) in enumerate(clustered_dupes):
    for record_id in cluster:
        for row in data:
            if record_id == int(row[0]):
                row = list(row)
                row.insert(0,cluster_id)
                row = tuple(row)
                full_data.append(row)
```

Is there any possible optimization for this part such that it produces the same result in less time complexity? Will this script work for 150 million records?

Comment: Consider doing the necessary duplication with SQL rather than in the Python code. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230295/whats-the-best-way-to-dedupe-a-table) might be able to help you get started

Comment: where `data` comes from? also `cluster_membership` seems to be unused in this snippet

Comment: @danielcorin I have gone through the link. There every solution is to remove duplicates but i want to find cluster of duplicate records from a postgres table instead to removing them.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov 'data' stores the result of select query on the postgres table. I have removed that 'cluster_membership' statement but still time taken is 163 seconds same as earlier.

Comment: provide us example of input and desired output