# Python/R: Remove duplicate rows - keep unique pairs of authors

Tags: python, r, duplicates, mapping, data-manipulation

It is an example I extract from my database. I am working with the visualization in co authorship, so based on this sample, I have to just keep one relationship in two authors. such as I have to delete one of Brian Norton---Maria Roo Ons or Maria Roo Ons---Brian Norton to keep the uniqueness of relationship.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|              article_title                                | author_name     |   coauthor_name |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Brian Norton    | Maria Roo Ons
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Brian Norton    | Max Ammann
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Brian Norton    | S. Shynu
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Brian Norton    | Sarah McCormack
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Maria Roo Ons   | Brian Norton
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Maria Roo Ons   | Max Ammann
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Maria Roo Ons   | S. Shynu
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Maria Roo Ons   | Sarah McCormack
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Max Ammann      | Brian Norton
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Max Ammann      | Maria Roo Ons
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Max Ammann      | S. Shynu
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Max Ammann      | Sarah McCormack
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | S. Shynu        | Brian Norton
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | S. Shynu        | Maria Roo Ons
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | S. Shynu        | Max Ammann
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | S. Shynu        | Sarah McCormack
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Sarah McCormack | Brian Norton
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Sarah McCormack | Maria Roo Ons
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Sarah McCormack | Max Ammann
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Sarah McCormack | S. Shynu
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the ideal final output is below.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|              article_title                                | author_name     |   coauthor_name |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Brian Norton    | Maria Roo Ons
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Brian Norton    | Max Ammann
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Brian Norton    | S. Shynu
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Brian Norton    | Sarah McCormack
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Maria Roo Ons   | Max Ammann
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Maria Roo Ons   | S. Shynu
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Maria Roo Ons   | Sarah McCormack
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Max Ammann      | S. Shynu
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | Max Ammann      | Sarah McCormack
A Metal Plate Solar Antenna for UMTS Pico-cell Base Station | S. Shynu        | Sarah McCormack
```

In this situation, I just want to keep one row. How do I deal with it in R or Python?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Are you using libraries/packages? (Numpy/Pandas for Python, dplyr or datatables for R)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a separate database and are using python to connect with it.

possible approaches:

1) You can add row-numbers based on the `article` column and then preform a de-duplication. you may check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230295/whats-the-best-way-to-dedupe-a-table) answer, for how to go about it in SQL.

Then you can just run the query using your python - db connector

2) You may pull the records into a pandas dataframe and do the analysis there. [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is good with handling and manipulating data.

Comment: Thank, I will try.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your dataframe looks like the one I have shown below since you have not shared what other possibilities could arise.

```
article author1 author2
A       a       b
A       b       a
A       a       a
A       b       b
```

In R, this is how I can get the rows you are looking for. I have assumed your dataframe is `df1`.

```
# This will create a new dataframe df2 with only those rows where author1 and author2 are different

df2 <- df1[df1$author1 != df1$author2, ]
```

The output looks like what you have provided in the question.

```
article author1 author2
  A       a       b
  A       b       a
```

Let me know if this is what you needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem is not delete repeating columns, the problem is how to delete duplicate if author1 and author2 have the same value but different order with same article.

Comment: When you say same value, do you mean both `author1` and `author2` should be `a`?

Comment: no, it means in the same article, I just need one record like: article A author1a author2b or  article A author1b author2a

Comment: See my updated answer. Since you have not provided a bigger dataset for me to fully test my code, I have assumed that the `author1` and `author2` will contain only `a` or `b`. Let me know if this solves it for you.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? If not would be glad to work over it with you!

Comment: Hi, thanks so much, and sorry for not familiar with this website, and I put an example below, could you please check, and I think its more clear.

Comment: Saw the example. Can you also provide a screenshot of how you want the final answer to be?

Comment: I just post it below as an answer.

Comment: I do not see any duplicates in your example under `author_name` and `coauthor_name`. It would really help how you want the final output to be by providing a screenshot.

Comment: I posted the final output.

Comment: I request you to edit your question with the example and final desired output rather than adding an answer.

Comment: That's a useful suggestion, I will modify it now.